# Changing background color of all activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a "Settings" activity in which you are shown 5 different color options to change the background or text or button color of the app to.

I'm focusing on simply the background change right now. From what I've read, I can do something like this using SharedPreferences:

Right now in my Settings class, I have the following code for each color option:

```
ImageButton changeBgRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bgRed);
changeBgRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("background", Color.RED);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

What confuses me is how to code my other classes so that they read in the color from the SharedPreference and change the background.

For my HomeScreen class, I have the following code/idea (I imagine the code could be copied/pasted into other activities for the most part):

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Background", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(settings.getInt("background", Color.RED) == Color.RED)
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    else
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I figure I would have more cases for the other colors. But right now, this doesn't work; when I run the app the background of the home screen starts red.

Am I not quite understanding how SharedPreferences works? Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: the color change comes to effect after and acitivity resumes or restarts, do you know that already?

Comment: Would it not be better to have different predefined `Themes` (Activity restart required once set)?  What if the user selects both red for the background, and red for text?

Comment: @Elltz As soon as I open the app, the background is already red even though I haven't added anything to my sharedpreferences. Maybe this is what's confusing me

Comment: `if(settings.getInt("background", Color.RED) == Color.RED)` is because of this line.. you see the second argument? its the default Color to return if the return object is null. is the confusion gone now?

Comment: @MarkKeen Yup, would be much better. But user want a full customization.

Comment: @Elltz So do you know what a solution to my problem would be? How could I do what I want to do?

Comment: Yes - looks like you are trying to access a Preference file called : `getSharedPreferences("Background" ..` in your Activity, however in your Preference Activity you only state `getPreferences` which will be the default preference file for the Preference Activity - bottom line you are trying to access preferences from different 2 xml files

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks. Fabio below helped me with that. This answered the first part of my question but unfortunately I'm not sure this is giving me the means to do what I want yet -- see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Activity documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), the `getPreferences()` method from the `Activity` class:

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's
>   class name as the preferences name.

So you are actually setting the color only for the Settings Activity, and you can't access this value from another Activity.

To fix this you could try the following code in the Settings class:

```
ImageButton changeBgRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bgRed); 
changeBgRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        // Changed the line below to get the same preferences used in Home Screen
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Background", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("background", Color.RED);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

This will be your Home Screen code, considering you want the white color background as default, and by clicking the `changeBgRed` view on Settings screen, it will turn your Home screen background red. Remember to uninstall your app and install again whenever you want to go back to the default state (white background)

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Background", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(settings.getInt("background", Color.WHITE) == Color.RED)
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    else
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: My Home class would stay the same? I'm still getting a red background on default.

Comment: This works to change the background of Home to red. Any thoughts on how I would be able to go back to Settings and pick a different color? Say the color is currently red and I pick green or blue